# "Unable to stop drive - timeout was reached" message long after safely removing USB drives

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 18.04

On Bionic 18.04, every time I use an USB drive (stick or 2.5" HD) I right-click the icon, select "Safely remove drive". The icon disappears, the drive powers down, and I unplug. Quite a bit later (I haven't timed it but it's at least 5-10 minutes or so) I get a pop-up that complains about "Unable to stop drive - timeout was reached".

In /var/log/messages I see the following:

```
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw udisksd[1043]: Powered off /dev/sdb - successfully wrote to sysfs path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/remove
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw gvfs-udisks2-vo[2117]: gvfs_udisks2_drive_stop_finish: assertion 'g_async_result_is_tagged (result, gvfs_udisks2_drive_stop)' failed
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw gvfs-udisks2-vo[2117]: g_dbus_method_invocation_return_gerror: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw gvfs-udisks2-vo[2117]: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw kernel: [31946.062127] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw upowerd[1293]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
May 26 13:01:48 dellfvw upowerd[1293]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I do not recognize this problem in my 18.04 LTS systems. I made fresh installs. How did make your system (fresh install or upgrade from a previous version)? Standard Ubuntu or a flavour (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ...)? I'm testing now: letting time pass after unmounting a USB pendrive like you describe ...).

Comment: After two hours I still have no complaint about "Unable to stop drive - timeout was reached" in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: New laptop (Dell Inspiron 3576) with brand new install. No lingering traces of W10 left on harddisk. :-)

Comment: I don't understand this. Maybe there is a problem with too new hardware or USB   system; "Unable to stop drive", that it wants to but does not manage to poweroff the drive. But it is only a vague guess. Let us hope that someone with more insight in HDD management will see your question and help you :-)

Comment: I confirm this issue. My system is upgraded from 17.10 while OP's system was a fresh install. I did not find many other mentions or bug reports on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. All 18.04s & derivatives come up with this message, with my Toshiba external HD. However if I use the gnome-disk-utility to unmount & power down all is well.

Comment: Why in the name of all that's unholy was this voted down? The bit about how using gnome-disks makes a difference is the sort of valuable information needed to track down the cause of the problem. I've been able to reproduce it, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

> I right-click the icon, select "Safely remove drive". The icon
>   disappears, the drive powers down, and I unplug.

I was doing the same until now and was confused about it, But I've found the solution. (:

---

## Steps

> 1. First, you'd have to **unmount** the external HDD. To do this you'd have to open the file manager. In my solution, I'd be using Nautilus which ships with the latest Ubuntu. Then you'd see a small icon beside your HDD'*s* name. Click that to unmount the drive.
>      [image: step 1: click that unmount sign which is highlighted]
> 2. Now you can right click on the drive and click on "Safely Remove Drive" to remove the drive safely.
>      [image]
> 3. Good job! Now the process is done and you'd see a notification that the drive can be safely removed.
>      [image: Voila!]

Comment: Please explain how this is a solution. The question indicates the drive is removed the way you now indicate as an answer, but nevertheless the  "Unable to stop drive - timeout was reached" appears sometimes a half hour later.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding that.

Comment: This looks clearer: you suggest to first unmount, then safely remove the drive. This may indeed be a suitable workaround to what in my opinion is a bug and a regression in 18.04. It would seem that "Safely remove drive" should automatically take care of all the steps needed to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, it should.  This _workaround_ has worked for me, please do tell me if it works for you too.